# ExtJS6 Sencha: Slowly hiding multiple columns

Tags: performance, extjs

I have a table (Ext.panel.Grid): 21 columns(Ext.grid.column.Column), 50 rows. Hiding with my button 20 columns takes about 2 seconds. I am using column.setVisible(true) method in a loop.
In the browser debugger - ext-all-debug.js, you can see that when you hide each column, a lot of time is spent on:

```
rootHeaderCt.onHeaderHide(me);
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

It's in the method hide() in Ext.grid.column.Column.

Is it possible to somehow speed up this process?

Comment: In case you wanna modify many columns, you can have a look at the reconfigure method of the grid. Sometimes it can be faster. But this also depends on your setup and column definitons (renderer, model associations, ...). https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-reconfigure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice.

This [post](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?310886-Hide-multiple-grid-columns-without-layout-inbetween&p=1193450&viewfull=1#post1193450) solved my problem.

Additionally used `Ext.suspendLayouts()` before multiple hiding/showing and `Ext.resumeLayouts()` after.

Answer (score 0):

grid.getView().getHeaderCt().suspendLayouts();

// hide columns

grid.getView().getHeaderCt().resumeLayouts(true);

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3978)